# Reducing Alphabet in nested for loops by reducing string by one char each line

Tags: java, for-loop

As a beginner, I'm given a loop assignment, and one of the loops is to output the alphabet, first from a-z, then b-z, then c-z, and so on, each on individual lines.

I've printed the alphabet by

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
```

And then a print statement produces the entire alphabet, but I'm at a loss as how to neatly implement another for loop to reduce the starting char and printing the new string of chars on a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(char j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
    for(char c = (char)('a' + j); c <= 'z'; c++) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried a similar statement earlier but apparently neglected a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
char input = 'a';
    while (input != 'z') // this will continue upto z == z
    {
        for (char c = input; c <= 'z'; c++) // get the input value and iterate upto z
        {
            System.out.print(c + " "); // print the values
        }
        System.out.println(""); // for next line
        input++; // this for next char like b,c,d....z
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the example code that should work for your purpose:

```
for(char outer='a'; outer <= 'z'; outer ++)
    {
    for(char inner = outer; inner <= 'z'; inner++)
       {
       System.out.print(""+inner); //print the character
       }
    System.out.println(""); // next line
    }
```

Basically, you have to cycle through the alphabet in the first for loop and you take the current value of the outer for loop as a starting value for the inner for loop.
And just a note: try to get used to give your variables names some sense - it does help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if statement at the end that returns it to 'b' when it's total iteration is less than 3. Then again, this question looks like an assignment.